# Android Facebook Integeration

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am working on Android Facebook integration. My question is,

if we are posting from different classes of an app on Facebook then what should be the class name that Facebook needs from us on time of creation an app on the Facebook Developer site ?

Comment: If you use facebook official app for login then it will redirect the user to specified activity of your app(which you provide in fb console)after successful login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook needs the Package name and your Main Activity to launch
so for example it can be MainActivity.java (it's your first class like a timline class or listview showing Friends updates)

[image]